# Publishing/Deploying Masterpages Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know of a way to "publish" (Perform all the action of publish) a masterpage in "Sharepoint 2010 Foundation"
I can do this really easy in "Sharepoint 2010 Standard"
However the publishing features aren't available in Foundation

Situation

I have 5+ sites each with 5 sub-sites

I would like to change one master page and then publish it to all the rest.

Rather than have to copy it to each site and then set as default for each.

as this is rather repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already sorted this one but if not then this is a handy little feature to install on to SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

http://spfmasterpageselect.codeplex.com/

It allows you to select a masterpage for a site collection/site and then push it down to all the sub sites.

Hope this helps.

Cheers